# Use array as function parameters

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrays

Given a function that returns an array, is it possible to "spread" the return values as the arguments to another function?

For example, I'd like to pass the result of `SPLIT("example.com,My Site", ",")` to the `HYPERLINK(url, [link_label])` function and have it treat `"My Site"` as the `link_label` parameter.

I've tried

```
=HYPERLINK(SPLIT("example.com,My Site", ","))
```

but it ignores the second argument.

(This is a simplified example. In reality, the function that's returning the URL and label is a QUERY which I'd like to avoid repeating in the second argument.)

Comment: Wrap your formula in ARRAYFORMULA()

like =ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(SPLIT("example.com,My Site", ",")))

Comment: @OlegS that doesn't work I'm afraid. It returns two cells – one with the link and no label, and one with the label and no link.

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK( 
    QUERY(SPLIT("example.com,My Site", ","),"Select Col1"),
    QUERY(SPLIT("example.com,My Site", ","),"Select Col2")))

Comment: Now the function call to get the arguments is repeated, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: HYPERLINK() requires 2 arguments, you can't avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Sheets' addition of the LET function enables storing intermediary calculation and addresses your need to limit repetition.

## LET

`QUERY(...)` is a placeholder for your other formula.

```
=LET(q,QUERY(...), ln,FIND(",",q), 
   HYPERLINK(LEFT(q, ln-1), MID(q, ln+1, LEN(q))))
```

Alternative using INDEX and SPLIT as in [Tedinoz's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/149000/)

```
=LET(q, SPLIT(QUERY(...), ","),
   HYPERLINK(INDEX(q,,1), INDEX(q,,2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your split string is `SPLIT("example.com,My Site", ",")`. The url is the first element, and the label is the second element.

Use Index to retrieve the separate elements of the split value. The paramaters returns the content of a cell, specified by row and column offset.

- First element: `=index(SPLIT("example.com,My Site", ","), 0, 1)` (row zero, column 1)
- Second element: `=index(SPLIT("example.com,My Site", ","), 0, 2)` (row zero, column 2)

Combine them in the hyperlink:

`=HYPERLINK(INDEX(SPLIT("example.com,My Site", ","), 0, 1), INDEX(SPLIT("example.com,My Site", ","), 0, 2))`

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets hasn't a "spread" operator. AFAIK there isn't a workaround for that when using built-in functions.